# Update reference in existing ChildEntity on ParentEntity save

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some `Child` entities that are already stored in the database. At some point, the user selects some entries adds them to a `Parent` and saves that `Parent`. The reference to the `Parent` in the `Child` does not get updated when calling the `JpaReposity.save` function of the `Parent`. **Do I need to manually update/save every child entity in the database?**

**Parent**

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends Base {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        if(this.children== null) { this.children= new ArrayList<>(); }
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
public class  Child extends Base{
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent= parent
        if(!parent.getChildren().contains(this)) {
            parent.getChildren().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {}
```

**Service**

```
@Transactional
Parent createAndSaveParent() {
    List<Child> children = this.childRepo.findAll();
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    children.forEach(c -> parent.addChild(c));
    return this.parentRepo.save(parent);
}
```

I am not getting any error, if I look at the returned `Parent` object after calling `save`, the children have the corrent parent set, but in the database the reference doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because of

```
mappedBy = "parent"
```

this means that the relationship is maintained by parent in the Child class and is responsible for setting the foreign key.

Comment: I thought about waiting to accept your answer in hope that this is not the case, guess it is, but just to verify one last time. I need to run through the list and call `save` on every Child element? (The references are updated in code - see `setParent`)

Comment: you don't have to call save on the child when you add CascadeType.PERSIST but you will have to set the parent on each child.

Comment: I can't set CascadeType.PERSIST, because the ChildEntites already exist in the database. I get an error when I add that option and after reading up on it that seemed to be the reason. (If I am wrong about that, please let me know)

Comment: @KenavR can you attach this error stack trace to question? What happens if you set  the PERSIST?